# Malformed OpenGL texture after calling CGBitmapContextCreateImage

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to use the contents of the UIView as an OpenGL texture. Here's how I obtain it:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

char *rawImage = malloc(4 * s.width * s.height);
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImage,
                                                   s.width,
                                                   s.height,
                                                   8,
                                                   4 * s.width,
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

[v.layer renderInContext:bitmapContext];

// converting ARGB to BGRA
for (int i = 0; i < s.width * s.height; i++) {
    int p = i * 4;

    char a = rawImage[p];
    char r = rawImage[p + 1];
    char g = rawImage[p + 2];
    char b = rawImage[p + 3];

    rawImage[p] = b;
    rawImage[p + 1] = g;
    rawImage[p + 2] = r;
    rawImage[p + 3] = a;
}


CFRelease(colorSpace);
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

return [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image options:nil error:nil];
```

This is the UIView I start with (note the small triangles at the top left corner):

[image: UIView]

This is what I get on an OpenGL surface after taking a snapshot:

[image: OpenGL surface]

It's clear that coordinates are mangled but I can't tell in which way and what do I do wrong. Is it a row byte alignment that goes wrong?

**UPDATE**: if I don't do color components swizzling (omitting ARGB to BGRA loop), here's the resulting picture:

[image: OpenGL surface, no color components swizzling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the picture above is what you're getting when you apply a texture that has the same ratio as the surface, but swap surface's `s` and `t` coordinates. Color components swizzling is still needed, though.

Comment: Can you post the working code here so others can benefit from your experience?

Answer (score 0):

Look like an alignment issue. I suggest putting a

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

before

```
return [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image options:nil error:nil];
```

Also you might mess up the alignment when doing that component swizzling, which BTW is completely unneccessary, as modern OpenGL directly support BGRA format.

Comment: Didn't help. Both `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` and `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);` result in the same picture

Comment: @SergeyMikhanov: See my edited answer. This is definitely an alignement issue, not a coordinate problem.

Comment: I removed the swizzling completely, see new picture attached to the question. Note that X and Y coordinates are swapped in both cases (you can see it in the button label) -- I think misalignment can't cause this

Comment: @SergeyMikhanov: That skew is definitely a misalignment issue. Also OpenGL assumes the pixel origin in the lower left. Any problems with texture coordinates remain obscure untill you post the source code of your drawing routine.